# Yii YUM User Management User::hasRole()

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to use the hasRole() method of the Yii extension User Management in order to verify the role of logged in users.

I am stricly following the official documentation https://github.com/thyseus/yii-user-management/blob/master/user/docs/install_tutorial.txt

```
User::hasRole('admin')
```

however I get a PHP warning

```
include(User.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The Yum modules are correctly called in the main.php config file
I have also tried with YumUser::hasRole()

Comment: Check your modules->user->models folder contains the file user.php. Also there are a few versions of the user module, try changing versions. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/

Comment: @JonPaulH there is no user.php file but YumUser.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that with the specific version of YUM that I have (version 0.8) I have to call the method of a different model, despite the documentation for that version stating otherwise

```
YumWebUser::hasRole('role_name')
```